# Convert jQuery code into pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem to convert the following code in jQuery, can someone show me an example please?

```
$('li').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find(':first-child').attr('href');
});​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: why do you need to convert it into pure javascript?

Comment: You could start with [DOM event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) and [query selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 3):

Details are commented in Snippet. By adding the event listener to the parent, we can utilize the capture, target, bubbling event phases to find out what element was actually clicked. This requires a simple investment of one simple event listener rather than a loop that adds several event listeners which is a little excessive. This procedure is called [event delegation](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm).

**SNIPPET**

```js
/*$('li').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).find(':first-child').attr('href');
});*/

//reference the parent of all li
var list = document.querySelector('ul');

//add event listener to ul that fires on any click 
//on any of it's children li or itself

list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  // if ATM the actual element that is clicked isn't the ul,
  // then declare that the e.target (it's the anchor that's 
  // clicked because it's the last element on the event chain)

  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    
    // Save the the e.target's href in a var tgt
    var tgt = e.target.href;
   
    // Assign your new location as the value of tgt
    window.location = tgt;
  }
console.log(tgt);
}, false);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href='http://example.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='http://www.w3shools.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='http://example.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='https://yahoo.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='http://example.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='https://developer.mozilla.org.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='http://example.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='https://google.com'>GO</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: To be thorough, you should add a guard against a null variable "list" with if (list) { ...

Comment: @RobApodaca like if there's no `<ul>` at all? I figure this situation would be  safe enough given the OP's selector is all `<li>`s, but you know it could've been a `<ol>`, huh?

Comment: Yes, if there is no ul element at all, then list.addEventListener will throw an error. document.querySelector can return null - therefore the code should always guard against that possibility unless throwing errors is acceptable for the app.

Answer (score 0):

A really useful tool for trying to cut ties with jQuery is: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

```js
// Grab all list items on the page
var listItems = new Array(document.getElementsByTagName('li'));

// function that will be assigned when the list item is clicked
function getHref(){
  // grab the first child's href
  window.location = this.querySelector(':first-child').getAttribute('href');
}

// loop through the list items and assign the function
for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i][0].addEventListener('click', getHref);
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="http://google.ca">Google</a>  
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>  
    </li>
</ul>
```